# Using @PrePersist and @PreUpdate with Ebean and Play 2.5.x not working?

Tags: java, playframework, orm, ebean

I have strange issue that I can't understand why is this working while I was following simple documented way to do it, I have the following Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    @CreatedTimestamp
    private DateTime createdDate;

    @Column
    @UpdatedTimestamp
    private DateTime updatedDate;

    @Column
    @Version
    private long version = 0;

    @Column(length = 35, nullable = false)
    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MinLength(2)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 35, nullable = false)
    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MinLength(2)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(length = 256)
    @Constraints.MaxLength(256)
    private String jobTitle;

    @Column(length = 1000)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String options;

    @Transient
    private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    @PrePersist
    protected void prePersist() throws IOException {
        Logger.warn("PrePersist called");
    }

    @PreUpdate
    protected void preUpdate() throws IOException {
        Logger.warn("PreUpdate called");
    }

    @PostLoad
    private void postLoad() throws IOException {
        Logger.warn("PostLoad called");
    }
// settlers and getters here 

}
```

Then for new user, I call in controller or service:

```
User user = new User();
user.setFirstName("Someone").setLastName("Last Name"); // etc
//then 
user.insert();
// or you can even try 
// user.save();
```

I'm trying to save new user and update user, getting user the break point while debugging not call the methods that have `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` and `@PostLoad` but they are not called at all, in real application I do some conversion from JSON string to Map `options` to `properties` and vice versa.

Supposed to be supported : http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/features/eventlistening

I'm using play 2.5.6 and [sbt-play-ebean](https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean/blob/master/build.sbt) 3.0.2 .

Comment: Don't your `User` class extends `com.avaje.ebean.Model`? What happens if you use `Ebean.save(user)` instead?

Comment: @Yes I extend Model, sorry removed it mistakenly, and yes tried `Ebean.save(user)` with no luck, I tried inside transaction block and no luck too.

Comment: make the method public

Comment: @MohdAlomar thanks a lot, my silly mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure is this a silly mistake or misunderstood, But the problem was the methods have wrong access modifiers.

They must be a `public`, not `protected` or `private`:

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() throws IOException {
    Logger.warn("PrePersist called");
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate() throws IOException {
    Logger.warn("PreUpdate called");
}

@PostLoad
public void postLoad() throws IOException {
    Logger.warn("PostLoad called");
}
```

Edit: just in case, if `@Transient` column modified,  `@PreUpdate` and `PrePersist` will not work.

Comment: Just note, \@Post... and \@Pre... also does not work with \@Lob columns